# Code duplication in Oracle queries

Tags: oracle

There is "code duplication" in sqls such as:

```
select to_char(date_col, 'ddmmyyyy'), types_col, max(some_value) 
from a_table 
group by to_char(date_col, 'ddmmyyyy'), types_col
order by to_char(date_col, 'ddmmyyyy'), types_col;
```

in this simple sql I need to duplicate "to_char(date_col, 'ddmmyyyy'), types_col" several times.
Is there a way to avoid the duplication (and I don't mean by using "sort by 1,2")?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 12c you can declare "local" [function.](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/with-clause-enhancements-12cr1). In previous Oracle releases you must use nested query and column aliases. I'm no aware of any other way.

Update:

```
with a1 as
(
 select to_char(date_col, 'ddmmyyyy') as date_str, a.*
 from a_table a
)
select date_str, types_col, max(some_value) 
from a1 
group date_str, types_col
order by date_str, types_col;
```

In 11g there is no other way.

Comment: column aliases don't work with group by.
And I'm using 11g, so can't use local functions (but good to know it exists, thanks)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this code block for your problem :

```
select k.date_col,k.types_col,max(k.some_value)
from (select to_char(a.date_col,'dd.mm.yyyy') as date_col, a.types_col, a.some_value from a_table a) k
group by k.date_col, types_col
order by k.date_col, k.types_col
```

For this data :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>date_col</td>
    <td>types_col</td>  
    <td>some_value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12.10.2015</td>
    <td>A</td>  
    <td>5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12.10.2015</td>
    <td>B</td>  
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>12.10.2015</td>
    <td>A</td>  
    <td>52</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Its gives this resulrts :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>date_col</td>
    <td>types_col</td>  
    <td>some_value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12.10.2015</td>
    <td>A</td>  
    <td>52</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>12.10.2015</td>
    <td>B</td>  
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Good Luck